# Android TCP/IP Socket Communication Fails To Return Data

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp

I am currently working on an Android app to be linked into an existing product for my employer. The system is a device running firmware that is controllable via serial, ethernet, or wi-fi using a .NET Windows program, direct serial communication, or a control webpage. The Android app is meant to auto-connect control webpage so that the device is controllable from a phone without anyone having to manually find IP addresses. In order to do that, I need to be able to find IP addresses and determine whether or not the address corresponds to one of these firmware devices.

Essentially what I want to do is run through all IP addresses that the Android sees and send each one to the method above. This thing should ping the address with a firmware command and see what is sent back to determine whether the address corresponds to a firmware device. I’ve been doing that at the moment by sending a command like "HOME" or "GETINFO" (correctly formatted for the firmware, of course) and comparing what, if anything is sent back with the expected response. Commands like home also have the benefit of causing a physical response, so we know without a microchip debugger if the command has at least been received.

As it stands I have the correct address hardcoded and sent in to this method. I know that the app can load the webpage controls successfully using the same address as a URL, so it must be correct and the connection must be good, but direct communication to the device is not working. No physical response is observed and no information is sent back—the Input stream just times out and returns -1. What’s stumping me so badly about this is that as far as I can tell, I’m sending information exactly the same way as the .NET Windows controls, and yet it isn’t working.

One further note: I’m aware that sending the IP Address string to the socket constructor as a hostname probably should not work, but since no UnknownHostException is thrown, I know that the socket can resolve it to an IP Address. Correct?

My code is as follows:

```
 private class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Boolean, Boolean> {    
  protected Boolean doInBackground(String... addr){
   try {
          String message = "<FHGETHUBINFO>";
          byte[] input = new byte[8];

          //addr is an array of string parameters containing a single IP address string. E.g. addr[0]=”192.168.199.108”  
          Socket s = new Socket(addr[0],80);

          //outgoing stream redirect to socket
          OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();
          out.write(message.getBytes());

          Log.v(TAG, "output sent. Waiting for input.");

          InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
          //Skip the exclamation mark and newline. Verified that nothing is received even without a skip.
          in.skip(2);
          int numBytes = in.read(input,0,8);
          Log.v(TAG, "Input received: "+numBytes);
          String st = input.toString();
          //Close connection
          s.close();

          if(st != "HUB INFO"){
                 return true;
          }
          else{
                 return false;
          }

   }

   catch (UnknownHostException e) {
          Log.v(TAG,"UnknownHostException: "+e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
   }

   catch (IOException e) {
          Log.v(TAG,"IOException: "+e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return false;
```

Thanks for any help you can give, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You are passing a single character string to socket().

Comment: You should probably call isReachable() on your socket after you create it.  No use proceeding if the address is not routable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed that I should be calling isReachable on the socket just for verification purposes, so thanks for the tip! However, it turned out the problem was that the device is not communicating on port 80, so the fact that I have the wrong port is definitely the source of the problem. Thank you for the advice, regardless.